# Does Reset.css affects other stylesheets?

Tags: css, css-reset

I am starting a new project, so i thought to start using Reset.css in my projects. i got the concept of using Reset.css, but one thing is bothering me is that does if affects my other style applied on the same element.. like in reset.css div have 0 margin and 0 padding... and if i apply margin to some of the divs in my stylesheet, wont it get disturbed?

Please clear my this doubt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not if the style applied to your other divs is more SPECIFIC.

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

In general any style applied using a class, or an id in the selector is going to take precedence over one which doesn't. But there are many other rules in this area you should become aware of.

i.e.

```
 div.myStyle {...}
```

will always overrule

```
 div {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include reset.css first and then include your own stylesheet file. and be sure that your styles wont be overwritten by reset.php.

Answer (score 0):

What you neeed to do is **load reset.css as a first style sheet.**
Anything else loaded after it will be overriding reset.css

e.g if you specify in reset css: p { margin: 0px; padding: 0px}
and than load style.css with style: p {margin: 2px; padding: 2px}

The style load as last one will be used.

I personaly use technic with

```
* { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: none; list-style: none;}
```

Put it at the top of css file and job done:) No need for extra .css fil.

Comment: "The style load as last one will be used." This is only true when all other factors are the same.

Comment: You can accept the answer if you are sure is correct and helpful.